# How to clean up from one meal for another on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cleaning

If after clearing the table on Shabbos there are lots of crumbs still left behind, how should one get rid of these properly?

- May one use their hands or mini broom to brush them into ones hand, dustbin, or trash?
- May one use the crumb collector (small metal object used in restaurants to collect crumbs)?
- May one shake the crumbs outside (assuming its in ones fenced backyard and carrying isn't an issue)?

Or is there another preferred method of doing so? Alternatively, must one just leave the crumbs as they are on the table cloth?

Comment: Re. shaking the crumbs outside, it depends on whether there is wind that can cause the crumbs to scatter when shaking out the cloth (if so, *zoreh* is an issue, see [here](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/hilshabbat/08hilshabbat.htm)).

Comment: I loosely fold the tablecloth, then take it to the sink and shake it there, or shake it over a large enough trash can.  I cannot vouch for whether either of these is recommended.

Comment: what about using a table scraper. the kind often used in restaurants? possible issue of M’macheik ?

Answer (score 2):

The Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim 337,5 brings down that the main problem with sweeping the crumbs is because of *Mashve Gumos* i.e levelling the ground which is the *melacha* (forbidden work on Shabbos) of building when sweeping on the bare ground.
However today since *all* houses have parquet floors (not bare ground) there is no decree of not sweeping house floors in case one sweeps a floor of a house on bare ground  levelling the ground:

> לכבד את הבית במכבדות שקורין בעזי"ם - הוה פלוגתא דרבוותא: הרי"ף מתיר לגמרי אפילו באינו מרוצף, דסבירא ליה שאין זה פסיק רישא שעל ידי זה ישוה גומות, והרמב"ם בפרק כ"א מתיר במרוצף ואוסר בשאינו מרוצף, דסבירא ליה דזהו פסיק רישא כמובן, דעל ידי הכיבוד קרוב לודאי שישוה את הגומות. מיהו במרוצף מותר, ולא גזרינן אטו שאינו מרוצף.ואף על גב דהוא בעצמו כתב שם: "אין סכין את הקרקע ולא מדיחים אותו ואין נופחין את הקרקע אפילו הוא מרוצף”, דגזרינן אטו שאינו מרוצף וכן מבואר בגמרא שם, מכל מקום בכיבוד דההכרח גדול לא גזרו (מ"מ).ודעת ר"י בעל התוספות והרא"ש דכיבוד אסור אפילו במרוצף, דגזרינן אטו שאינו מרוצף. וכתב רבינו הרמ"א בסעיף ב' שכן המנהג ואין לשנות ע"ש **אמנם אצלינו מכבדים מטעם דכל הרצפות שלנו מרוצפין ולא שייך לגזור אטו אינו מרוצף, דאפילו עיר אחת אטו עיר אחרת לא גזרינן כמ"ש, וכל שכן האידנא שבכל המקומות מרוצפין הרצפות**. ואין חילוק בין רצופי עץ לרצופי אבנים ולא חיישינן לההפסקות שבין אבן לאבן, דלענין כיבוד ליכא חשש זה, דמעט הוא ההפסק שבין רובד לרובד

So one *can* use a broom to get rid of crumbs on the floor, and use a brush or ones hands to remove crumbs from the table. I cannot specify regards to all crumb collectors a though i am told in general its merely a fancy rotary brush moved manually with compartment for crumb collection so it should be OK though CYLOR incase there might be different models.

Shaking the white table cloth on Shabbos is permitted as explained by the Mishna Brura 302,1 5 one can shake a white or red clothing from its dust (though one may not shake new black clothing) so where there is an Eiruv and no wind to aid the dispersing of the crumbs (to prevent *zoreh*) it is permitted.

> כשמנער טליתו מן האבק והעפר שנבלע בו וחייב משום מלבן ודוקא בחדתי ובאוכמי אבל בעתיקי או בחיוורי וסומקי לית לן בה כמבואר שם וכמו לעיל לענין טל וכונת הרב נמי דוקא בחדתי ובאוכמי והאי דנקט בלשון איסור לאשמעינן דאם אינו מקפיד אפילו איסורא לית בה